# Uninheriting a font-family in css

Tags: css

I am hacking away at a wordpress theme and do not wish to make changes to the main stylesheet, style.css, so all changes need to go into style-custom.css

The stylesheet applies a font-family style to a certain class, but I want that class to defer to the globally defined font.

So this is how the inheritance is working:

style.css:383

```
div#main-superfish-wrapper ul {
  font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
}
```

style.css:10

```
body {
  font-family: Droid Sans;
}
```

in style-custom.css, I simply wish to cancel out the style defined at style.css:383 and revert to the original definition at style.css:10.  I don't wish to redefine the font-family.

Is this possible in straight css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use the [inherit](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#value-def-inherit) keyword:

```
div#main-superfish-wrapper ul {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if any of the intermediate elements (such as `div#main-superfish-wrapper` or any elements between these and the page body) have other `font-family` styles, this will inherit from those intermediate elements instead of the page body.

Comment: Perfect answer and super fast, thanks very much.  Always nice to learn something new (that I probably should already know :) )!